# Inconsistencies with report layout in SSRS 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Using SSRS, I am creating a report that will show some payroll information. The desired layout is to have one page consist of a single employee's information for a single paycheck. It seemed to me that having a List and putting rectangles in it was the best way.

The problem is that I want black borders on each rectangle/text box, and they are appearing inconsistent. In Design/Preview mode in Visual Studio, it looks just how I would like. However, when I deploy to the server, it does not. Thoughts?

**This is how it looks in the Design/Preview mode in VS**
[image]

**This is how it looks when deployed to the server. Notice the type and check date fields have space between them as well as the Job Class and Empl. Type fields, and the Printed field has grown vertically a little. NOTE: This is mock data**
[image]

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you use Tablixes?

Comment: No @3N1GM4. However, what would be the best way to use a table to only display one record per page? I have seen a tutorial at (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBYn1DU3VMQ&index=5&list=PL7A29088C98E92D5F) which describes a way to group records so that they would only display one record per page(the video shows by 10, but same concept) but it seems hacky when a list is meant for this (one record per page). I just refuse to believe a top tier enterprise application acts in this manner--I must be doing something wrong :)

Comment: Don't use lists, use tables. The trick is to wrap the entire page in a cell that keeps everything together. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41248281/ssrs-multiple-tables-per-report-page-grouped-by-common-column/41252133#41252133

Comment: @StevenWhite Right on, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need go to the Build-->select your Project and click on deployment the changes which were made by you will reflect in the SSRS Report.