# SSRS - Multiple tables per report page grouped by common column

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have two tables, let's say table A and table B. Both tables are dynamic in that they return different quantities of rows for each row group. Table A is grouped on columns A, B, C. Table B is grouped on the same columns A and B, but not C. So I have the following tables:

Column A and B are the same between both tables.

I want to place both tables on each page where each page is grouped by A. In other words, there will be a separate page for each value of column A with both tables appearing on each page.

I have tried doing this by embedding the two tables in a list but I get the static inner members error. I cannot put the tables into a header row because the number of rows is dynamic. Is there any way to do this in SSRS?

I am using SSRS 2008 R2.

Comment: After doing this, did you run into an error, "ssrs the tablix has a detail member with inner members?"  If you do, follow the steps found at (http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/dbprogramming/reporting-services-error-the-tablix/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to group everything by Column A and have separate pages for it, let's use that as the starting point.

1. Create a table with one detail row that is grouped by Column A.
2. Insert a Rectangle into it as a placeholder.
3. Drag both Table A and Table B into it.

It should look like this:

[image]

So whatever rows or columns Tables A and B have, it will all be within the context of each instance of Column A.