# Repeat entire Table data on multiple pages - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I currently building one report in which the same data has to be repeated on multiple pages.
- So, I have a field (Quantity) based on which I have to decide the times' data has to be displayed. For example, if the quantity is 5, the report has to print 5 pages with each page printing the same data. This is usually used when we print Shipment labels.

Is it possible to achive this in SSRS. Grouping would have solved my issue but since the value that I have is a scalar, I am not sure if it is possible.

Any inputs/Suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat contents on multiple pages by placing it all inside a grouped cell. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252133/2033717) for more detailed instructions on that. For this particular case, you would want to have a column in your dataset that has the desired quantity.

One way to do this would be to cross join your query with a subquery that has your desired quantity. Then you can group by the new column and get the same data within every instance of it.