# Heading on Vertical report

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I created a vertical report and I want to add the header on each page that this report displays.How can I do it? I want the report and the heading to be vertical. If its horizontal:

[image]

I can add a page header but what can I do if this vertical ? In The picture I want The first 3 rows to be repeated in every page. How can I get the heading for the vertical report ?

Comment: Make the first three rows in the page header, and set it to repeat on a page break.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is meant to be printed, you're not expecting users to read the report sideways. Have you considered changing the paper orientation in the report instead? That way everything could be designed horizontally and still print out as expected.

If you absolutely need it to be vertical, you could use a nested column group to repeat content on each page. However, this may have unintended consequences depending on how you plan to export it since it is not really a standard practice. If you run into specific issues with this, I would recommend posting a separate question to see if there are workarounds.

Comment: Thank you I will look into it. The requirement is the vertical report as they need it to be portrait when printing it ,with a bunch of their reports in a continuous report of pdf's that are a mix of portraits and landscapes so I had to make this vertical.

Comment: OK. I have a technique posted here that can be adapted to your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41252133/2033717

Comment: Default printing in portrait/landscape depends on report page width / height. Eg for A4 size width = 21, height =29.7, reversing the width and height values will make SSRS print by default to landscape